# What is the expected status code for a succesful login

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

What is the status code a backend should return when someone gets succesfully logged into an application? The response might be either an html or a json.

LE: I believe I have to choose between 200 OK and 204 No Content, not sure which one to use and why

Comment: Any reason not to return 200?

Comment: Are you planning to do something different when performing a login? If not return 200. Can you maybe describe how the login is performed, which calls are made?

Comment: @sanyash I believe 200 is ok, but I wanted to be sure, thanks

Comment: @Wiingreen it is a very basic login that takes a json with an email and a password and searches the user in a database. Nothing really unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 OK

or if you need to redirect then one of the redirect status codes